# How to update Java to 7 on max OSX?

Tags: java, macos

When I type

```
java -version
```

into my terminal, I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

However, I downloaded Java 7. One of the differences between Java 6 and Java 7 is that when I open System Preferences (Mac), I can see an icon to launch the Java control panel. I can see the Java control panel, which means that Java 7 has been downloaded properly. So how do I change my settings/configuration so that it uses the newest version that I downloaded?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a mac? If yes, have you tried this -https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_java_update.xml?

Comment: do mac have environment variables?

Comment: I think this should help you:  [Clicky!](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)

Comment: @BheshGurung : Yes, I'm using a mac. I have done that and it says I already have the recommended Java version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Java 7 and Apple Java 6 are completely different and they coexist on the same machine as they inhabit totally separate locations.

**Java 7**, if installed, lives in:

`/Library/"Internet Plug-Ins"/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

**Java 6**, if installed, lives in:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/`

(And the more traditional Java 6 JDK is at: `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`)

When you type `java`, you're running `/usr/bin/java`, which is a symbolic link to Java 6. In fact, if you type `ls -l /usr/bin | grep -i java` you will see a bunch of symbolic links for the typical JDK/JRE executables.

So if you have installed Java 7, and that's what you want to use from the command line, you can change into its directory and run its specific binaries in `bin`. To avoid that, you can add its `bin` directory to your Bash search path, so its contents are invoked instead of the Java 6 symlinks in `/usr/bin`. To do this, alter `/etc/paths` to add the `bin` directory before the first line:

```
{ echo "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin"; \
  cat /etc/paths; } | sudo tee /etc/paths > /dev/null
```

Then set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, so supporting software knows where to find Java 7:

```
{ echo -n "export JAVA_HOME=";
echo "/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"; } \
| sudo tee -a /etc/bashrc > /dev/null
```

Now, in any new Terminal window, when you type `java -version`, you'll see `java version "1.7.0_51"`. (And if you still want to be able to run the Java 6 binaries, you can call them with `/usr/bin/java`, `/usr/bin/javac`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try issuing the following command:

```
update-alternatives –config java
```

That command will make you able to choose between Java versions. This command worked for me
on a Linux-based machine, so I think there would be no different than a Mac, but I'm not sure, you could try it out.

Comment: @user3025403, then the only way to change the Java version is by setting/changing the Java environment variables. If you google it up, you will find enough questions and answers about it. Good luck!

Comment: `update-alternatives` is specific to the Debian package management system. OS X doesn't have any kind of included package management system at all, so this won't work; and none of the third-party ones that exist (Homebrew, MacPorts, Fink) use this mechanism.